# WebMatrix SQL injection & XSS concerns after paramaterizing queries

Tags: c#, security, validation, razor, webmatrix

I have a simple question that concerns security in WebMatrix razor (C#)

I (for a very brief period of time) considered using character checking to help validate forms to combat SQL injection, however, after realizing that parameterizing queries is the best way to combat this, I have since commented out this check which looks something like this:

```
    foreach(char c in POIName)
    {
        if(c=='\'' || c=='$' || c=='\"' || c=='&' || c=='%' || c=='@' || c=='-' || c=='<' || c=='>')
        {
            errorMessage = "You have entered at least one invalid character in the \"POI Name\" field. Invalid characters are: [\'], [\"], [&], [$], [@], [-], [<], [>], and [%]";
        }
    }
```

Now, my question is this:
Should I remove lines like these entirely, as they are not needed (to allow maximum user freedom in textareas etc.) or should there still be some character checking specific to WebMatrix (or not specific to it for that matter).

Perhaps not allow "@" or ";" or "<" or ">"??

From what I understand paramaterizing the queries (as I have) auto escapes harmful characters and re-wraps the whole thing as a string (or something like that anyway, lol), and my database has proven impervious to any of the SQL injection attacks I have thrown at it.

I guess I am concerned because I am not sure if razor can be effected somehow or if I should worry about XSS (no I am not a blog or anything that should ever accept html tags or even angle brackets of any kind).

Sorry if this question is kind of all over the place, but I don't know where else to turn to find as definitive of an answer as Stack Overflow usually provides (e.g., I trust this community much more than a few Google searches, which I assure I have tried before posting).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, two points here.  You are talking about engaging in "Black Listing" in order to scrub user input.  The better approach is "[White Listing](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet)".  Define what the allowed characters are.  There are many ways in which an attacker can creatively get around a quickly constructed Black List.

Secondly, [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) is a tricky beast.  Encoding and White Listing can be used to combat it.  I would recommend looking at [Microsofts Ant-XSS Library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) for advice. But generally, you're going to want to use an encoding that's appropriate to the section of the page you are trying to protect.

In summary, the best advice I can give you is to become familiar with OWASP, specifically the [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main).  It's an amazing resource for securing your applications.

Comment: +1 for OWASP - I had no idea that it existed, let alone existed for 11 years.

Comment: @xelco52 That's good advice, thank you.  And thanks for the website, although I'm not sure where to go to get the resources for securing my applications, but it seems a resourceful site.  Are you familiar at all with WebMatrix?  I wonder how thorough it is, because its validation 'seems' really good (e.g., it won't allow anything through that has anything [at all] enclosed in angle brackets).  Is this still not enough? (XSS does, as you suggest, seem a tricky beast, so not sure)

Comment: Regardless which database solution you use, it is worth noting that an attacker has a very large arsenal when trying to persist an XSS attack in a database.  Different character sets, encodings, spaces...etc.  Ultimately, you should be actively preventing XSS wheverever you are taking user supplied data and persisting it in a database, and when you are taking data out of a database to be displayed to the user.  I will update the general OWASP link to point to the "OWASP Top 10" :)

Comment: @xelco52 Well, thanks for the site it has given me much to review, it has for the most part encouraged me and help me see that at least with the methodology, that I have been moving in the right direction, great site, great answer, Thanks!

Comment: @VoidKing, the built in validation you are referring to is standard ASP.NET Request Validation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339.aspx